# How to make the code accept both int and float type values as double type? - Python

Tags: python, types, floating-point, integer, double

I have dataset which have mixed values, in which few values are float(e.g. 3.4) and few are int (e.g. 3.0). I want to check if all the values are double. I want that if the values are either int or float, they are accepted as double datatype.

I tried doing:

```py
data = [3.0, 3.4, 3.2, 3.0, 3.1]

for valuedata in data:
  is_double = isinstance(valuedata, float)
  print(is_double)
```

The result is coming out to be FALSE, where as i want that int and float both should be accepted as double.

Thanks

Comment: 3.0 is a float, not an int - at least in Python 3. Are you using Python 3 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for multiple allowed types by passing a tuple to `isinstance()`:

```
is_double = isinstance(valuedata, (int, float))
```

Also note that Python's `int` has unlimited precision, which could be too large to fit into a C/C++ `double`.

Answer (score 2):

You can see if it's an instance of numbers.Number.

```
>>> import numbers
>>> isinstance(1.1, numbers.Number)
True
>>> isinstance(1, numbers.Number)  
True
>>>
```